# Upper bound of a function within an interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I am trying to find the upper bound of the magnitude of a function within a given interval.

Here is the problem:

Find an upper bound on $|\partial f / \partial y|$ for the following function on the given domain:
$$
f(t, y)=\operatorname{ty} \sin (\beta y), \quad t \in[0,1], \quad y \in[-\pi, \pi]
$$
Here, $\beta$ is a fixed parameter. Your upper bound will depend on $\beta$.

I have currently gotten to the inequality: $|\partial f / \partial y|\leq |\sin(\beta y)+\beta y \cos(\beta y)|$

But from here I cannot see how I can further simplify this in order to remove the y dependence in the inequality. I don't see what else can be done without knowing any more information about $\beta$. Have I overlooked something that can allow me to strengthen the inequality?

More precisely I am trying to find a Lipschitz constant for those who are familiar with this procedure

Comment: Why don't you use the assumption on $y$?

Comment: @uniquesolution I'm not sure what you mean, can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One bound, possibly not the best, can be obtained by
$$|\sin(\beta y)+\beta y\cos(\beta y)|\leq |\sin(\beta y)|+|\beta y||\cos(\beta y)|\leq 1+\pi|\beta|$$
where the assumption on $y$, namely, $y\in[-\pi,\pi]$, was used.

Comment: Is splitting up the magnitude like that valid? I don't see how $\sin(\beta y)$ can be 1 whilst $\cos(\beta y)$ is also equal to 1. Although their individual maximums are indeed 1, I don't think they can be both taken as 1 when they both depend in the same way on y. Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: Apparently you are grossly ignoring the elementary fact that the absolute value of the cosine and sine functions are both bounded above by the $1$. They need not be simultaneously equal to $1$, and in fact they never are, in order for that to be true. Or maybe it is the triangle inequality you are unaware of?

Comment: I did not think applying the triangle inequality here would be valid but since we are only trying to find a constant which will set a bound to the maximum of the function then I think it makes sense. We are only trying to find a reasonable bound. thanks